# Upgrade for Qualcomm QCWB335 (Kubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, wireless, kubuntu, hardware, pcie

I have an Asus laptop and I've recently switched over to linux (kubuntu 18.04) - loving it by the way!

My question is which half pcie wifi adapter (to get a 5ghz and get as much out of my 400mbps connection) should I get that is well supported by my OS? I don't want to spend too much. I have tried the usb adapter options, but I keep breaking the mini USBs when they're in my bag and the ones with the antenna are just annoying!

Thank you in advance and sorry if there's any info missing!

PS: Can someone comment and tell me if I can add any half pci-e card in that slot?

**uname -a:**

```
Linux aftab-kubuntu-1804 4.18.0-25-generic #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 27 07:28:31 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**lspci:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1566
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R3 Graphics]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 156b
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1537
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 02)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller (rev 01)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1580
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1581
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1582
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1583
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1584
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1585
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

Current card:
[image: Current half pcie card]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the photo that you posted, it is quite easy to replace the wireless card in your laptop: remove one screw, detach the antenna connectors and slide the old card out of its slot. Install the new card by the reverse procedure.

In your case, there are three other considerations. First is whitelisting. Please see: https://goughlui.com/2014/08/02/laptop-wireless-card-whitelists-an-upgrade-nightmare/ However, as you see from the article:

> At this time, it is known that some recent Lenovo, Toshiba, Dell, HP
>   and Compaq follow this whitelisting practice. From my experience, it
>   appears that Asus, Acer, and MSI don’t.

It appears, therefore, that you may use any half-PCIe card that you wish.

The second consideration is to pick a card that does 5 gHz; that is, 802.11N and 802.11AC. The third consideration is, of course, that the card be plug and play and reliable in Ubuntu Linux. There are many such cards available. I have had excellent success with Intel cards and currently use an Intel 7260. Here is a reference list of Intel cards: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html I suggest that you pick any of the cards with the suffix Wireless-AC. Also, note that some cards are available in both N and AC versions. Choose carefully when shopping.

There are other reliable 802.11N/AC cards that work well in Linux. I haven't tried them all. Perhaps others will offer suggestions.

Comment: Thank you! Much more detailed than I was expecting.